# Is it possible to include an installed_app's template in your app's template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django app **TestApp**. In the templates directory of TestApp, I have an **test_template.html**. TestApp's settings.py has a reusable app (in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list) I created called **reusable_app**. There is a template called `reusable_template.html` in the templates directory of this reusable app.

**Is it possible to include reusable_template.html in the test_template.html using the {% include} tag?**

I tried `{% include "reusable_app/templates/reusable_template.html" %}` in test_template.html but got a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception.

I also tried:

1. `from django.template.loader import get_template`
2. `get_template('reusable_app/templates/reusable_template.html')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django will look inside the app's `templates` directory, so you shouldn't specify this in the path. This should work:

```
{% include "reusable_template.html" %}
```

This assumes of course that the only app with a template called `reusable_template.html` is your `reusable_app`.

To minimise the risk of template collisions it is common to have a subdirectory in your app's `templates` directory, so that the path to the template is `reusableapp/templates/reusableapp/reusable_template.html`. You would then include it with:

```
{% include "reuseable_app/reusable_template.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project structure:

```
  +app
  |
  +project/urls.py
  |       |
  |       +wsgi.py
  |       |
  |       +settings.py
  | 
  +templates/base.html
  |
  +static/
```

then your template has to be in

```
  +app+
  |   |
  |   +templates/your_app_base.html
  |             | 
  |             +your_tempplate.html
  +project/urls.py
  |       |
  |       +wsgi.py
  |       |
  |       +settings.py
  | 
  +templates/base.html
  |
  +static/
```

Django first checks your apps's templates directory and if does not find templates, takes it from the main template directory. Make sure your template loaders are configured in settings.py